# Copying from a cell, into a new comment below and moving on to doing it again

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I've looked all over and only find little snippets that don't seem to work together.

Using VBA, I'm trying to copy the information from a cell into a comment on the cell below it; I then want to move on to the next cell and repeat 10 times.

It'll be so useful to make a table much more compact so that it's easier to view the important information, and then when you hover over a cell you see the comment (which gives you a piece of support information).

So in row 1: I want to copy A1 into the comments of A2 and then do the same for B,C,D,E etc up to J.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Comments()
   Dim c As Range, d As String

   For Each c In Selection
      If c <> "" Then d = d & c & Chr(10)
   Next

   Range("A2").Comment.Delete
   Range("A2").AddComment d
End Sub
```

The Range needs to be the dynamic part - copying from A1 and pasting into the comment of A2 and then repeating so that it copies from B1 into comments of B2 etc..

I hope that makes sense...

Comment: show us please what have you tried so far

Comment: Thank you - so far I have: Sub Comments()

Dim c As Range, d As String
For Each c In Selection
    If c <> "" Then d = d & c & Chr(10)
Next
Range("E42").Comment.Delete
Range("E42").AddComment d
End Sub       The Range needs to be the dynamic part that is below the current selection instead of E42... When I get that right, I can move onto the next cell up to J..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub CommentAdder()
    Dim r As Range, Big As Range
    Set Big = Range("A1:J1")
    Big.Offset(1, 0).ClearComments
    For Each r In Big
        v = r.Text
        With r.Offset(1, 0)
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Visible = False
            .Comment.Text Text:=v
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary - Thank you, this worked straight away. I'm a beginner novice at this, so it's a big help thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Range
    'change Sheet1 to suit
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J1")
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            With c.Offset(1) ' Offset(1) means get cell below
                On Error Resume Next
                .Comment.Delete ' delete comment if it's already exist
                On Error GoTo 0
                .AddComment Text:=CStr(c.Value) 'add new comment
            End With
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm - it doesn't like the ".AddComment Text..." line. it's returning an application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: have you changed something in my code? it should work

Comment: I didn't change anything but - it's ok, I have now changed the code to be .Range("A2:J2") as I think the offset didn't work in from row 1..

Comment: @simoco:   **Try placing a number in the top row.**